# How to add/remove a star other than yellow when selecting multiple emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I've enabled custom stars in gmail, and can set them for individual emails, e.g. a green checkmark. But I can't figure out how to change all the emails in a folder so they're starred with a custom star, like a green checkmark, when all have been selected. When selecting multiple emails, the only thing I seem to be able to do is star and unstar with the default yellow star.